# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,501,907' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table column like:

[image: imdbVotes Column]

and I want this column as int. I have this query:

```
ALTER TABLE imdb
ALTER COLUMN imdbVotes int;
```

The result is an error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
> the nvarchar value '1,501,907' to data type int.

How can i solve that?

Comment: Remove the commas (`,`) first, then convert. Numerical values don't have formatting in an RDBMS.

Comment: Don't have such a column in the first place. Don't store numbers as *localized* text. You'll have to parse these strings into integers, using the correct locale. Removing commas may or may not be enough. Worst case, the column contains mixed locales, eg `1,234.567` and `1.234,567`, in which case it may not be possible to make a correct conversion. Slightly better, the column may contain non-numeric text. That's actually better, because those are definitely garbage

Comment: Thank you for replies, @PanagiotisKanavos, yes you are right, although in this case i dont have decimal (after dot) numbers. And i can't enough understand you, what do you mean in "localized text" ?

Comment: @Hacktan [more than half the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg) uses `.` as the thousand separator. If it wasn't for China, one could say that *most* of the world uses `.` as the thousand separator. And then there's India that separates hundreds, not thousands.

Comment: @Hacktan Parsing that string in the EMEA area is ..... interesting, as in *most* cases (by population) the thousand separator will be `.` in some African countries it will be `,` and ME countries seem to be using U+066B, which to me looks just like a comma. You'll have to verify what's used by your customers before trying to convert production data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database, it is advised to store the data without any formatting. In this case, I assume that data is formatted in US Locale with comma separator for every three digits.

You have to replace , and then store the value

```sql
UPDATE TableName
SET imdbVotes = REPLACE(imedVotes,',','')
```

Once you have updated the values, you can apply conversion.

```sql
ALTER TABLE TableName
ALTER COLUMN imdbVotes INT
```

Comment: Thank you... And i have one question too:
'14 Oct 1994' a have i colum filled like this, how can i convert to date?

Comment: @Hacktan . . . This answers the question you asked here.  If you have a new question, it should be asked as a *new* question.