# Convert '14 Oct 1994' string to SQL date column type

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table column like:

[image]

How can i convert this to a sql date type column?

Comment: Learn from the mistake in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68344391/2029983) fix the design. Store data in a correctly strongly typed column; [`varchar` is not a "one size fits all" data type](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-varchar-is-not-a-one-size-fits-all-data-type/).

Comment: What, however, is wrong with `CONVERT`/`CAST` here?

Comment: can't you use cast? SELECT CAST( '14 Oct 1994' AS DATE) works fine.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, but what you meaning when saying "fix the design". I got datas from .txt file and when i import, i selected all columns as varchar, because import was failing otherwise.

Comment: By fix the design I *literally* mean fix it. To repeat myself, [`varchar` is not a "one size fits all" data type](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-varchar-is-not-a-one-size-fits-all-data-type/); your columns should be the appropriate data type to start with. Clearly, for the above, it should be a `date` not a `varchar`. If you are/were getting errors during the import then you might have bad data, or you should use a staging table. Perhaps the former is what you are doing here? But that doesn't explain why `CAST`/`CONVERT` doesn't work.

Comment: Try `CONVERT(date, released, 106)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, yourColumn) AS YourColumn
FROM yourTable
```